# Which player should I use for displaying videos on my site?

Tags: video-streaming

I need to add a user uploaded video section to my site. There'll plenty of videos. Any recommendations? It doesn't have to be free and preferably a non-flash one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wimpy has a video player](http://www.wimpyplayer.com/products/wimpy_rave.html) (not free). I haven't used it, but I have used their audio player and was impressed. The only downside was that it was slightly annoying to configure. But they may have improved that since I last looked.

Answer (score 1):

Use mediaplayer.swf.
[Click here to download](http://fliiby.com/get/269625/mediaplayer-na0nngzqfd.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use flowplayer.Its an open source one. IF you dont need swf, you can use silverlight's media control ,if you are using ASP.NET